# EditreturnI cannot quite get the idea of the recursive function asked here (c++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, recursion

I am currently doing some excercises in c++, but I somehow cannot wrap my head about this question:

> Create a function named bin that, that takes two integer arguments: n
>   and k, and returns an integer. If k is equal to 0 or n is smaller than
>   k, this function has to return 1. In any other case, this function
>   should return the sum of bin(n-1, k-1) and bin(n-1, k).

A function in the form `int bin (int x, int y)`, with `if  (n == 0 || n"<"k) { return 1;}` and `else { bin (n-1, k-1); bin (n-1, k),` with the `else bin` being created before as `bin ( double x, double y) {  return x+y;` .

Or something like that. I can not quite put my finger on the goal of the task.

```
`    int bin(int n, int k)
{
if (k == 0 || n<k)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    cout<< bin (n-1, k-1) + bin (n-1, k);
}
}

int main ()
{
int n;
int k;
cout <<" Please enter a value for n\n";
cin >> n;
cout << "Please enter a value for k\n";
cin >> k;
int result = bin (n, k);
cout << result;
```

}
   `

Edit: It seems I got most of it right from the beginnign and it was really as easy as I thought, maybe a mental blockade.

But thanks everyone. I do not think I ever experinces such a fast and efficient community, maybe I will be of use for other questions, someday.

Comment: It'd be great if you could post your code. :)

Comment: Please post your real function instead of a long sentence with pieces of code. And what is actually your question? *"What the purpose of such function?"* or *"How do I write such function?"*.

Comment: ok I will one moment please

Comment: your code so far forgets about the return value

Comment: I just managed to use the editor properly. Thank you for your time and answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of translating english into c++ isn't it?

```
// Create a function named bin that, that takes two integer arguments: n and k, 
//and returns an integer. 
int bin(int n, int k)
{
  // If k is equal to 0 or n is smaller than k, this function has to return 1. 
  if ((k == 0) || n < k)
    return 1;

  //In any other case, this function should return the sum of 
  // bin(n-1, k-1) and bin(n-1, k).
  return bin(n-1, k-1) + bin(n-1, k);
}
```

Comment: `unsigned` would be better than `int`.  As written, `bin(-1,-2)` will recurse until integer overflow.  (Mind you, the whole thing is probably going to cause stack overflow anyway. )

Comment: thank you so much, I still have trouble just implenting my code with the editor  and I already got answers.

Comment: @MartinBonner `unsigned long long` might be better... this rabbit hole could last forever

Answer (score 2):

By reading your text literally, the solution is straightforward:

```
int bin(int n, int k) {
  if (k == 0 || n < k)
    return 1;

  return binomial(n-1, k-1) + binomial(n-1, k);
}
```

but **careful**: if this is the definition of a trivial [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) implementation, you're doing it wrong since the text is wrong: the termination condition is to check whether `k == 0` or `n == k`

```
int binomial(int n, int k) {
  if (k == 0 || n == k)
    return 1;

  return binomial(n-1, k-1) + binomial(n-1, k);
}
```

For completeness' sake notice that there are also other faster approaches (e.g. [dynamic programming](http://marcodiiga.github.io/calculating-binomial-coefficients) ones to compute it in `O(NK)`)

Comment: thank you as well.. Your remark put some light on the matter for me